# ValueError: Both `input_dim` and `output_dim` should be positive, Received input_dim = 10000 and output_dim = 0

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, attention-model

I use the code below and I got the error
ValueError: Both `input_dim` and `output_dim` should be positive, Received input_dim = 10000 and output_dim = 0 this code must train the model using deep learning methods to step of validation

```
#Ensemple-Deep Model Architecture
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
#Channel Attention-BiLSTM

inp = Input(shape=(maxlen,))
x = Embedding(max_features, embed_size, weights=[embedding_matrix], trainable=False)(inp)

Att_LSTM = Bidirectional(LSTM(64, return_sequences=True,))(x)
Att_LSTM = Attention(maxlen)(Att_LSTM)
Att_LSTM = Dense(64, activation="relu")(Att_LSTM)
Output_Att_LSTM = Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(Att_LSTM)

#Channel Atttention-BiGRU
Att_GRU = Bidirectional(GRU(64, return_sequences=True,))(x)
Att_GRU = Attention(maxlen)(Att_GRU)
Att_GRU = Dense(64, activation="relu")(Att_GRU)
Output_Att_GRU = Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(Att_GRU)

#Channel  CNN
Att_CNN = Conv1D(64, kernel_size=3, activation = "relu") (x)
Att_CNN = MaxPooling1D()(Att_CNN)
Att_CNN = Flatten()(Att_CNN)

#MLP
Att_CNN = Dense(64, activation="relu")(Att_CNN)
Att_CNN = Dropout(0.2) (Att_CNN)
Output_Att_CNN = Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(Att_CNN)

# Concatination
merged = concatenate([Output_Att_CNN, Output_Att_GRU, Output_Att_LSTM])

# Interpretation
outputs = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(merged)
model = Model(inputs=inp, outputs=outputs)

# Compile
model.compile( loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I expect to train my model using deep learning methods mentioned in my code

Comment: Please post the full stack trace for the error.

Comment: please tell me how to do that this is the first time I submit a question on stack overflow